# Add track to playlist Deezer API

Tags: javascript, api, deezer

My question is how can I add a song to a playlist created earlier from the javascript SDK.
I'm trying to do:

```
        DZ.api('user/me/playlists/'+ ID_NEW_PLAYLIST + '/tracks', 'POST', {songs: 2342342}, function(response){
           console.log(response);
        });
```

And too:

```
        DZ.api('playlists/'+ ID_NEW_PLAYLIST + '/tracks', 'POST', {songs: 3135556}, function(response){
           console.log(response);
        });
```

But it does not work.

The ID_NEW_PLAYLIST is the id of the playlist you created earlier.

I await your reply, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here http://developers.deezer.com/api/playlist/tracks, the good request to do is

DZ.api('playlist/'+ ID_NEW_PLAYLIST + '/tracks', 'POST', {songs: 3135556}, function(response){
   console.log(response);
});

without the S in playlist.